# Which space vehicle had the most interior, pressurized cabin space?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight

According to [NASA's Space Shuttle Basics page](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/basics/orbit.html), the Space Shuttle had 74.3 cubic meters (2,625 cubic feet) of pressurized cabin space. That provided its largest crew of 8 with only 328 cubic feet per person! (roughly 7ft in all directions)

That leaves me wondering: which space vehicle has/had the most interior pressurized cabin space? Are all so small?

Comment: Skylab had "a habitable volume of about 354 cubic meters (12,700 cubic. ft.)" source: https://history.nasa.gov/EP-107/ch4.htm

Comment: The [single biggest "room" in space has been Skylab](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/largest-inhabitable-volume-in-space), the largest volume in total surely is ISS, and I _guess_ the largest cabin volume was the Space Shuttle. So, what are you after?

Comment: The reason I asked, is curiosity about how much personal space might be available on a long trips in space. But I reframed the question to something more concrete so it is answerable.

Comment: Please ask which one had the best sound system next ;-)

Comment: Hmm I guess I could edit to include space per person. and other prospective interstellar crewed capsules.

Comment: Shuttle cabin volume differed, and was much larger, if the mission included a Spacelab or Spacehab in the payload bay.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Largest inhabitable volume in space](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/largest-inhabitable-volume-in-space)

Comment: @Organic Marble: I searched and didn't see that one. I am sorry, I try to avoid dups. My intent was to find out if the shuttle's cabin was comparably large or small.

Comment: This question has a better answer.

Comment: Funny, I assumed space stations like the ISS would not be considered "vehicles" for this question, but the accepted answer is the ISS.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I didn't accept the answer because it said "ISS", rather because it provided enough organized and supported information to answer my questions. Organic Marble's additions have been very informative as well.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The space vehicle with the largest interior pressurised cabin volume is the International Space Station with a pressurised volume of 931.57 m<sup>3</sup>. It's habitable volume of 388 m<sup>3</sup> is only slightly larger than Skylab, which had a habitable volume of 351.6 m<sup>3</sup>.

Habitable space tends to be limited to the minimum in orbiters and proposed interplanetary craft to reduce the mass, requiring less fuel or being able to use current rockets to launch the space craft. Space stations are able to be larger as they are built in modules, their subsequent sections are combined to calculate the total final volume.

List of manned spacecraft and their pressurised/habitable volumes past and present. All volumes with a ***** are habitable volumes (usually significantly smaller than total pressurised volume).

#### Current

1. ISS: [931.57 m<sup>3</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station), [388 m<sup>3</sup>*](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/facts-and-figures)
2. Tianggong-2: [14 m<sup>3</sup>](https://chinaspacereport.com/spacecraft/tiangong2/)
3. Soyuz MS: [10.5 m<sup>3</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_MS) (Largest Soyuz craft according to [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_(spacecraft)#Specifications))
4. ShenZhou: [8 m<sup>3</sup>](https://chinaspacereport.com/spacecraft/shenzhou/)

#### Past

- Skylab: [351.6 m <sup>3</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylab)
- Mir: [350 m<sup>3</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir), Core Module [90 m<sup>3</sup>*](https://history.nasa.gov/SP-4225/mir/mir.htm)
- Salyut 5: [100 m<sup>3</sup>*](https://www.webcitation.org/5il9QixAg?url=http://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/TRS/_techrep/RP1357.pdf)(pp 90)
- Salyut 1-4, 6-7: [90 m<sup>3</sup>*](https://www.webcitation.org/5il9QixAg?url=http://ston.jsc.nasa.gov/collections/TRS/_techrep/RP1357.pdf)(pp 66-75)
- Space Shuttle: [74.3 m<sup>3</sup>*†](https://spaceflight.nasa.gov/shuttle/reference/basics/orbit.html)
- Almaz: [47.5 m<sup>3</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almaz)
- Tiangong-1: [15 m<sup>3</sup>*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiangong-1)
- Apollo: C/SM [6.2 m<sup>3</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Command/Service_Module), LM [6.7 m<sup>3</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module)
- Vostok: [2-3 m<sup>3</sup>*](https://books.google.ch/books?id=y3zoCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&lpg=PA128&dq=Vostok+pressurized+volume&source=bl&ots=gpt2SYpB9_&sig=qADT5LgpYTSereuu06TmeFWmqdE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiL09Lp-rPZAhVBzaQKHfH-AdgQ6AEIaTAH#v=onepage&q=Vostok%20pressurized%20volume&f=false)
- Voskhod: Supposedly the same as above (Vostok), with more [habitable space](https://books.google.ch/books?id=Kk10eqF6lXcC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=voskhod+pressurised+volume&source=bl&ots=qlketP1Mb5&sig=BzygbY3z0XunZoFM_RYvI5aj3fw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGsPiOgLTZAhXGyaQKHVtqD9gQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=voskhod%20pressurised%20volume&f=false).
- Mercury: [2.8 m<sup>3</sup>](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19670005605.pdf) (pp 47)
- Gemini: [2.25m<sup>3</sup>*](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/nmc/spacecraftDisplay.do?id=1966-047A)

#### Proposed

Bigelow Aerospace has proposed a possible space station with a habitable volume of [3000 m<sup>3</sup>](https://www.popularmechanics.com/space/a6247/bigelow-aerospace-ba2100-hotel/). This would be by far the largest manned spacecraft.

---

<sub>† The Shuttle habitable volume *only* includes the basic crew cabin, without any additional habitable modules (as pointed out by [@OrganicMarble](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/6944/organic-marble) in the [comments](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/25519/which-space-vehicle-had-the-most-interior-pressurized-cabin-space/25521?noredirect=1#comment74035_25521))</sub>

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but not the part about Shuttle. Its cabin volume differed, and was much larger, if the mission included a Spacelab or Spacehab in the payload bay. It also varied depending on whether the Orbiter was fitted with an internal or external airlock.

Comment: @OrganicMarble if I understand you correctly, you're saying the size of the crew cabin changed depending on what was in the payload bay? I've just taken my information from the linked page, and looking about haven't found any other numbers.

Comment: Yeah, those modules were habitable volumes linked to the basic crew cabin. https://media.gettyimages.com/photos/diagram-showing-three-ways-in-which-the-spacelab-module-could-be-on-picture-id90738990

Comment: @OrganicMarble so the basic crew cabin was 74.3 cubic metres? Then, in my opinion pointing it out as such is sufficient for now.

Comment: Sure, as you wish. But the OP is underestimating the volume per crewmember for shuttle, those big crews were on Spacelab or Spacehab missions.

Comment: When I look closer into volume per person I'll try to find more accurate data for the various STS' and missions with larger volumes.

Comment: I'll post a supplemental answer.

Comment: What's the difference between pressurized volume and habitable volume for the ISS? The space taken up by equipment?

Comment: @Hobbes: my understanding is that the shuttle had 3 pressurized decks, but only two were available to crew. The bottom deck required pulling up the removable floorboards to reach storage and access equipment.

Comment: @Hobbes supposedly, everything that's filled with experiments, equipment, machines, etc. I myself was surprised by the significant difference.

Comment: I think you meant 'interplanetary', not 'interstellar', so i went ahead and changed that.

Comment: What's the distinction between a pressurized volume and a habitable one? If it's pressurized, why isn't it also "habitable"?

Comment: @Harabeck Because, as above, the space could be filled with equipment, storage, machines, etc. It certainly is "habitable" but it's not a space a human could live in, as they wouldn't fit, or whatever

Answer (score 12):

Supplemental answer to [Edlothiad](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/18175/edlothiad)'s (which reaches the correct conclusion).

Shuttle cabin volume varied based on its configuration and whether a habitable module was flown in the payload bay.

- Crew cabin with internal airlock - 70 m^3
- Crew cabin with external airlock - 76 m^3
- Crew cabin with external airlock and tunnel adapter - 80 m^3
- Crew cabin, external airlock, tunnel adapter, and Spacehab - 117 m^3
- Crew cabin, external airlock, tunnel adapter, and Spacehab double
  module - 150 m^3

Spacelab volume was approximately 60 m^3, its flights included a tunnel adapter as well.  It's been so long since it flew, I can't find detailed information.

Source: SMS Systems Console Handbook

Comment: That is useful info! I suspect this aligned with the larger crews as the shuttle crew varied between 5-8 astronauts.

Comment: You are correct, especially in the pre-ISS days, the largest crews were on Spacelab missions.