# How big can solar sails be?

Tags: propulsion, solar-sail, design

If you really, really, don't care about getting from one place in space to another quickly, a solar sail can be a good option. A solar sail is light (no pun intended) and requires no onboard fuel. At first glance, it sounds like an aerospace engineer's dream. The big issue, though, is that it takes a long time to accelerate to meaningful speeds. The problem can be tamed a little by making the solar sail bigger, but that means that it can become unwieldy (and thus harder to deploy), and a little hard to stuff into a rocket. So once again, here I go with a "size" question:

How big can solar sails *reasonably* become (assuming finite resources)? What are the biggest ones currently on the drawing board?

Finally, as called2voyage has pointed out, you could make a very large solar sail with "an asteroid and a 3-D printer." Is space-based manufacturing a *reasonable* option?

Comment: What if I told you that you didn't have to stuff it in a rocket? Give me an asteroid and a 3-D printer and I'll make you as big a sail as resources and structural engineering will allow.

Comment: @called2voyage Haha. I figured someone was going to bring up space-based manufacturing, although perhaps using different methods. I'll edit the question to see if I can cut that loophole.

Comment: Space-based manufacturing isn't a reasonable option... yet.

Comment: @briligg You're referring to conclusions in recently published [National Research Council study](http://www.nap.edu/openbook.php?record_id=18871)? Because it's been widely criticised for lack of vision and suggesting even more boards, panels, forums and alike should be established to "support" NASA endeavors in space-based additive manufacturing. They seem to prefer NASA would only 3D print more red tape in space. And we all know that red tape doesn't make for a particularly good solar sail. One does not reach space by anchoring in Washington.

Comment: This question has a close vote as "primarily opinion-based" - i.e. facts would be hard to find. Could the voter justify that? Seems similar, in principle, to http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/819/are-there-any-theoretical-size-limits-of-man-made-space-stations-structures

Comment: @HDE226868 It may be that the downvoter has trouble with the word "reasonably". I'm not sure why though, as far as the main question goes. It is fairly clear that you are talking about the limits of what can be launched. The question about whether space-based manufacturing is reasonable is a little more subjective, however, as phrased.

Comment: As far as my comment goes, i just tend to fondly think of a far future, past a tipping point where space is a net economic loss. Spit-balling about why the question might get a close vote and hasn't been answered - doesn't it depend a lot on how thin you can make your material? Thus, doesn't it depend largely on your manufacturing technique, and your budget? And what about about assembly of sections in space? Maybe this question suffers from being so future-focused it is hard to put bounds on it (as my questions also tend to).

Comment: While I don't know the limits I can see there would be limits.  The bigger your sail the longer the cords that connect the sail to your spacecraft must be.  Those cords have weight.  Thus the bigger your sail the lower the ratio of sail area to total weight.

Comment: @LorenPechtel but that is a theoretical limit, which is itself affected by where the sail will be used - if it is going to Venus it can tolerate a lower ratio than if it is going to Jupiter.

Comment: For extremely large solar sails they would have to be spun to maintain their shape and you can translate their resistance to momentum change anyway. So I'd say that the size limit would be defined by fabric's tensile strength with its outer edges constantly radially accelerating w.r.t. its center, i.e. producing the so-called centrifugal force. While it could be strengthened by support structures, this cannot go on indefinitely and at one point you reach material or mass limits. Questions are then which materials are we talking of, where would it be deployed, and does it have to go anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a complete answer (there really isn't one, since what's considered "reasonable" will vary with the person answering), but:

With current technology, assuming that we didn't do fabrication in space (which would allow much thinner sails that don't require folding and packing in a rocket), and without relying on anything that hasn't been developed yet, solar sails can be made of 2 µm thick Mylar, which has [a density of 1.39 g/cc](http://www.grafixplastics.com/mylar_prop.asp), not counting the extremely thin layer of aluminum deposited onto it.  This works out to approximately 360 m^2 per kilogram.  Assuming the heaviest-lift booster for 2015 will be a Falcon Heavy (53,000 kg to LEO), that works out to 19 km^2, or if you prefer, a circular solar sail about 4.9 kilometers in diameter.

Note that this doesn't include the weight of the rigging, control systems, and so on that would be required, I just wanted to give a rough guide.

The best bet for a near-future solar sail really would be space-based manufacturing, though. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail#Materials), an engineer named Eric Drexler has created 0.1 µm aluminum film using vapor deposition. Space-based manufacturing (presumably using an asteroid as feedstock) would allow arbitrarily large solar-sails to be constructed.